# Работа со списками, Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, список

Как вывести первые три элемента из середины списка?

Comment: этот вопрос можно трактовать по-разному. Приведите пример в вопросе

Comment: У нас есть список с неопределенным количеством элементов в нем. Есть ли универсальный способ,  которым можно решить эту проблему(то есть он работает при любых длинах списков)?

Comment: для того, чтобы ответить на ваш вопрос его необходимо понять. Формулировка вопроса размытая. Приведите пример исходного списка и то, что вы хотите из него получить

Comment: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @ЛЮТОВОЛК имеется в виду что-то такое? https://repl.it/repls/ClientsideWrithingProperty

Comment: @вася, да. Я имел ввиду это

Comment: @ЛЮТОВОЛК перевёл в ответ

Answer (score 2):

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] 

a_mid = len(a) // 2 - 1

print(a[a_mid], a[a_mid + 1], a[a_mid + 2])
```

Answer (score 1):

Я нашел еще один способ решения данного вопросаа:

```
lst = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 1, 2, 3]
need_index = len(lst) // 2
print(lst[need_index:need_index+3])
```